# Random.UUID in WebRTC Signaling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, webrtc

I've read threw a couple examples of setting up video chat on android using WebRTC.

During the signaling processes, I've `UUID.randomUUID()`, to generate a unique id for the users involved in the burgeoning connection.

I am using Firebase to authenticate users. Is it possible to the UID generated by `Firebase Auth` as the unique id or is there a reason I should use `UUID.randomUUID()` specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Authentication UID assigned to a user is most definitely unique, otherwise many features of the Firebase platform would not work well at all.  With this available, there's rarely a need to generate a UUID for a user.